# I want to popup a window 3 minutes after the user enters the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

As the title says i want to  pop up a window 3 minutes after the user enters the site. The problem is since a user wont stay on a single page for 3 minutes. I cant use javascript. since he might navigate to different pages in my website. I tried using setTimeout but it wont work if i navigate to a different page the code gets refreshed again.

Comment: you need to carry the count as a URL parameter across pages. It's a hack but it would work albeit a bit innacurate.

Comment: it's better to calculate time at server side. Also, you can use cookie、localstore to store time at client time,  in this case , the client could change the time easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good use for sessionStorage:

1. On initial page load, check for existence of sessionStorage item
2. If the item doesn't exist, populate it with the current date/time
3. If the item does exist use setInterval to poll and compare the time, say every 100 ms. If 3 minutes has passed, pop the message.

sessionStorage values will persist across pages and page reloads.

Example:

```
// Save date to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('your-key', new Date());

// Get saved date from sessionStorage
var date = sessionStorage.getItem('your-key');
```

You'd probably want to fall back to localstorage and then cookies if you use this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session at server side. Put the session start time in a session variable. Each time a new page is requested, you can return the session start time. Then, feed this DateTime as well as current server DateTime to your global javascript function which will take care of further calculations as well as displaying the popup.

Remember here that I am fetching current DateTime also from server since javascript detected DateTime, in most cases, is different than the server DateTime (due to hosting location, etc.). With this solution, The only demerit is  you won't be able to track the lagging caused by client server roundtrip.